# Why does map and flatMap behave very differently on a LazyMapCollection?

Tags: dictionary, swift2

I have a simple dictionary with String keys and integer values.  I wanted to take the integer values from the dictionary and perform an operation on them.  An ideal use case for maps.  So I tried the following:

```
    let testDict = ["Test0":0, "Test1":1, "Test2":2]
    let testValues = testDict.values  // Returns a LazyMapCollection

    let mapResult = testValues.map( {number in "$\(number).00"} )
    print( "mapResult: \(mapResult)" )

    let mapFlatResult = testValues.flatMap( {number in "$\(number).00"} )
    print( "mapFlatResult: \(mapFlatResult)" )
```

The mapResult is not what I expected.  It returned a LazyMapCollection of a LazyMapCollection of a Dictionary.  However, flatMap did return what I expected an array of strings.

> mapResult: LazyMapCollection, Int>, String>(_base:
>   Swift.LazyMapCollection,
>   Swift.Int>(_base: ["Test1": 1, "Test2": 2, "Test0": 0], _transform:
>   (Function)), _transform: (Function))
>
> mapFlatResult: ["$1.00", "$2.00", "$0.00"]

Why the difference in implementing between map and flatMap?  Is this what map should be doing?

If the LazyMapCollection is turned into an Array it does do the mapping as expected:

```
    print( "mapResult2: " + String(Array(mapResult)) )
```

> mapResult2: ["$1.00", "$2.00", "$0.00"]

Comment: I do realize that this could also have been implemented without using the .values property by doing a map directly on the dictionary testDict.map( {(key, value) in "$\(value).00"} ).  However, the question goes more to why is map and flatMap working differently on a LazyMapCollection.

Comment: Here is a nice article on the difference between flatmap and map.  http://www.uraimo.com/2015/10/08/Swift2-map-flatmap-demystified/?utm_campaign=This%2BWeek%2Bin%2BSwift&utm_medium=email&utm_source=This_Week_in_Swift_58